# How to make a compound legend with color tag that correspond to the relative abundance plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bioinformatics

I want to reproduce a figure from the following [paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41590-020-0602-z). [image: Fig.1c]

It's stuck at separating the X1 column. I want to use regex, but could not figure out how to.
I have a plan to separate each word by underscore separator (I got a lists), then extract [-tes & -ria] and [-ceae] suffixed word into Phylum and Family, respectively. After that, words after family should be gathered into Genus. For accuracy, maybe conditions for "unclassified" and word less than 5 characters shall be grouped to the preceded word.

Also, is it possible to add small color tag to each family that correspond to the relative abundances plot?

```
library(tidyverse)
james <- read_csv("tableS2a.csv")
james <- james %>% mutate(
    Cecum = rowSums(select(james, contains("Caecum"))),
    Transverse = rowSums(select(james, contains("Transv"))),
    Sigmoid = rowSums(select(james, contains("Sigmoi")))
  )
james2 <- james %>% 
  select(X1, Cecum, Transverse, Sigmoid) 

james.tab <- james2 %>%
  mutate(meanAbundance = 
           rowMeans(
             column_to_rownames(james2, var = "X1")
             )
         ) %>%
  arrange(desc(meanAbundance)) %>%
  top_n(30, meanAbundance) # extract top30

write.csv2(james.tab, "jamestab.csv")

james.tab2 <- 
  as.data.frame(
    apply(
      select(
        james.tab, 
        Cecum, 
        Transverse, 
        Sigmoid), 2, 
      function(x) x / sum(x) * 100)
    )

james.tab3 <-
  bind_cols(
    as.data.frame(
      select(james.tab, X1)), 
    as.data.frame(james.tab2)
    )

james.X1 <- select(james.tab3, X1)

# Separate X1 to Phylum(-tes/-ria), Family (-ceae), and genus
james.list <- strsplit(pull(james.X1, X1), "_")
james.class <-
  if_else(grepl("(ceae)", james.X1) == T,
          mutate(james.X1, Family =
                   grep(
                     "[[:alpha:]]ceae(_)", 
                     strsplit(pull(james.X1, X1), "_"), 
                     value = T
                   )))
```

I am new to R, those code above are mostly pasted from my previous work. Pardon me if the code is inefficient.  Dataset: [Original table](https://static-content.springer.com/esm/art%3A10.1038%2Fs41590-020-0602-z/MediaObjects/41590_2020_602_MOESM3_ESM.xlsx) -> [Top30 csv (pastebin)](https://pastebin.pl/view/raw/d996bb6e)

APPEND

This is the recent results
I did not successfully implement ggtext package, maybe wrong address in theme?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(patchwork)
library(ggtext)
library(glue)

james <- read_csv("tableS2a.csv")
james2 <- james %>% 
  mutate(
  Cecum = rowSums(select(james, contains("Caecum"))),
  Transverse = rowSums(select(james, contains("Transv"))),
  Sigmoid = rowSums(select(james, contains("Sigmoi")))
  ) %>% 
  select(X1, Cecum, Transverse, Sigmoid) %>% 
  filter(grepl("(ceae)", james$X1)) # Filter rows with -ceae suffix only

# extract family value with selecting -ceae/les suffix word
family.naming0 <-
  regmatches(james2$X1,
             regexpr("(?<=_)(.*?(ceae|les)(?=_))", james2$X1, perl = T))
#in between "_" to fail-safe double -ceae. E.g. Bacteria_Bacteriaceae_Aceae

family.naming1 <-
  regmatches(james2$X1, regexpr("(?<=ceae_|les_)\\d", james2$X1, perl = T))

family.naming2 <- 
  regmatches(james2$X1, regexpr("(?<=ceae_|les_)unclassified", james2$X1, perl = T))

family.naming3 <-
  ifelse(
    grepl("(?<=[(ceae_)|(les_)])\\d", james2$X1, perl = T),
    paste0(family.naming0, " ", family.naming1),
    ifelse(
      grepl("(?<=[(ceae_)|(les_)])unclassified", james2$X1, perl = T),
      paste0(family.naming0, " ", family.naming2),
      paste0(family.naming0)
    ))  

james3 <- james2 %>% 
  gather("Cecum", "Transverse", "Sigmoid", key = "location", value = "abundance") %>% 
  mutate(relativeAbundance=abundance/sum(abundance) * 100) %>%
  mutate(phylum=gsub("(_.*)","", X1)) %>% # extract phylum value with selecting first word
  mutate(family=
           ifelse(
             grepl("(?<=[(ceae_)|(les_)])\\d", X1, perl = T),
             paste0(family.naming0, " ", family.naming1),
             ifelse(
               grepl("(?<=[(ceae_)|(les_)])unclassified", X1, perl = T),
               paste0(family.naming0, " ", family.naming2),
               paste0(family.naming0)
             ))) %>% 
  mutate(genus=gsub("_", " ", sub("(.*ceae)+?_((unclassified|\\d)*(_)*)", "", X1)))

# change it into percentage
james4 <-
  bind_cols(select(james2, X1), as.data.frame(
    apply(
      select(
        james2, 
        Cecum, 
        Transverse, 
        Sigmoid), 2, 
      function(x) x / sum(x) * 100)))

jamesReg <- james4 %>% 
  mutate(james4, 
         meanAbundance=rowMeans(select(james4, Cecum, Transverse, Sigmoid))) %>% 
  arrange(desc(meanAbundance)) %>% 
  top_n(30, meanAbundance) %>% 
  pull(X1)

# collect top 30 from james4X reference
james5 <- james3 %>% 
  filter(X1 %in% jamesReg)

# change order
james5$location_f <- 
  factor(james5$location, labels = c("Cecum", "Transverse", "Sigmoid"))

james6 <- 
  select(james5, location_f, relativeAbundance, genus)

# First plot
james.plot <-
  ggplot(james6,
         aes(x = location_f, y = relativeAbundance, fill = genus)) +
  geom_bar(position = "fill", stat = "identity", show.legend = F) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format(accuracy = 1)) + # y axis percentage
  #theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank()) +
  ylab("Relative abundances (%)") +
  scale_fill_hue(l=60, c=80)


james.table <- data.frame("relativeAbundance"=james5$relativeAbundance[1:30]+
                            james5$relativeAbundance[31:60]+
                            james5$relativeAbundance[61:90],
                          "phylum"=james5$phylum[1:30],
                          "family"=james5$family[1:30],
                          "genus"=james5$genus[1:30])

# get colour pattern 
ggplotColours <- function(n = 6, h = c(0, 360) + 15) {
  if ((diff(h) %% 360) < 1)
    h[2] <- h[2] - 360 / n
  hcl(h = (seq(h[1], h[2], length = n)), c = 100, l = 65)
}

family <- pull(select(james.table, family))
genus <- pull(select(james.table, genus))
james.table2 <- james.table %>% 
  mutate(color=ggplotColours(nrow(james.table))) %>% # just in case 
  mutate(asv=glue("{family}: <i>{genus}</i>"))

# color for long vertical tile (phylum tile)
james.phyl.col <- c("#fddb47", "#58b9b2", "#6585c3", "#e25a4b")

# legend making or second plot
james.legend <- 
  ggplot(james.table2, aes(y = asv)) +
  geom_tile(aes(x = 1, fill = asv), width = 0.9, height = 0.9) +
  geom_tile(aes(x = 0.2), 
            fill = james.phyl.col[as.numeric(as.factor(james.table2$phylum))], 
            width = 0.4) +
  scale_y_discrete(position = "right", expand = c(0,0),
                   name = "") +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0,0), breaks = NULL, name = "") +
  scale_fill_discrete(guide = "none") +
  facet_grid(phylum ~ ., scales = "free_y", space = "free_y",
             switch = "y") +
  theme(axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        aspect.ratio = 1,
        axis.text.y = element_markdown())

# patchwork
james.plot + james.legend
```

Final image [final](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYVor.png)

Comment: I don't think this is a native possibility in ggplot2, but you could probably mess around in the grid system to achieve the effect you'd like. However, as you're new to R, this might be a bit tricky to get exactly right.

Comment: Hi @teunbrand! Could you point out which keyword I should be looking for? Is it grid system of ggplot? Is it possible to extract variable/row color value from gg object? Maybe it is better to make them separately, then combine with patchwork or alike?

Comment: Yeah it is the `grid` package and the `gtable` package. A starting point would be to call `ggplotGrob(my_ggplot_object)` and mess around in that. Making them seperately and patchworking them together is also a good idea!

Comment: Hi, I am currently trying on making the second part. I think it is possible to make them with `ggplotColours()` function, although it won't be as versatile as I thought in the future. Do you have any idea how to make second plot? I am thinking on making small heatmap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example on how you could begin making the legend as a separate plot, which you can later patchwork next to the main plot.

Basically you're making tiles for every item and then you facet them by group. It is a bit tricky to get the tiles exactly 1:1 with facets, so you'd have to play a bit with the `width = ...` and `height = ...` to make it look right.

```r
library(ggplot2)

# Example of item-group relations
df <- data.frame(
  group = c("Actinobacteria", "Actinobacteria", "Bacteroidetes", "Bacteroidetes",
            "Firmicutes", "Firmicutes", "Firmicutes"),
  item = c("Bifidobacteriaceae", "Coriobacteriaceae",
           "Bacteroidaceae", "Porphyromonadacea",
           "Acidaminococcacaea", "Clostridiacea", "Clostridiales")
)

group_colours <- c("blue", "green", "red")

ggplot(df, aes(y = item)) +
  geom_tile(aes(x = 1, fill = item), width = 0.9, height = 0.9) +
  geom_tile(aes(x = 0.2), 
            fill = group_colours[as.numeric(as.factor(df$group))], 
            width = 0.4) +
  scale_y_discrete(position = "right", expand = c(0,0),
                   name = "") +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0,0), breaks = NULL, name = "") +
  scale_fill_discrete(guide = "none") +
  facet_grid(group ~ ., scales = "free_y", space = "free_y",
             switch = "y") +
  theme(axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        aspect.ratio = 1)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-08-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Awesome thanks! geom_tile is the key! Btw, do you have any idea how to fix subscript out of bounds error? I try ggplotGrob but upon str-ing the object it return the error everytime. Edit: I am new to stackoverflow too, kindly let me know if I am off topic and should open new query instead.

Comment: I'm not sure of the context in which this error occurs so it is hard to say, but I can imagine `fill = group_colours[as.numeric(as.factor(df$group))]` throwing that error. The fix would typically be to give an equal amount of colours as you have groups in the `group_colours` variable.

Comment: I am sorry for being unclear. I was trying to `str()` my `ggplotGrob()` object, it turned the "subscript out of bounds" error. Thank you for the tip! Anyway, I have gotten the colors from the legend! It is on `james.gtable<-ggplotGrobs(james.plot)` and then `james.gtable$grobs[[15]]$grobs$"99_bcd2bc442c81652d80f816640caed205"$grobs[[4]][["gp"]][["fill"]]`. However I can't figure out how to see the pattern, the only thing I know is that only `rect, grob` type that have these colors. And I can only hope they are not randomly arrange, even so, I hope there are `structure` library lying somewhere.

Comment: Ah I see. Yeah that might be an issue with gtable. I'm not sure what larger goal you're trying to pursue though. Whenever it is possible to circumvent working with the gtable objects, I'd rather do it in ggplot than in gtable.

Comment: Hi, I am successfully remaking the "plot". Is it okay to post the code along with the picture here as an answer? It is not finished yet, maybe you can help me with it. E.g how to italicize, reorder the tile label, missing upper actinobacteria phylum, and different color of small square tile.

Comment: I think a better option would be to append it to your question or file a new question. For text markup a good place to look would be the ggtext package (https://github.com/wilkelab/ggtext).